# Javascript - How can I get an alert when the div is 100% on left?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I get an alert when the div with the classname "earth", is 100% on the left? Please don't use jQuery, thank you! I tried using `setTimeout`, but I was hoping there was another way, without having to depend on the time, but on the position

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .earth {
        position :relative;
        animation:move 10s linear;
        background:red;
        height:20px;
        width:20px;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes move
    {
        from { left: 0%;  }
        to { left: 100%; }
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    function changetext () {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
        animation();
    }

    function animation() {
        document.getElementById('ghost').className ='earth';
    }

    function repeat() {
        var sd = document.getElementById("ghost").className = 'earth';
        sd.style.display = 'none';
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="something"></div>
    <div id="ghost"> </div>
    <p onclick="changetext();" id="demo"> HELLO WORLD </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend) event:

```js
var anim = document.querySelector(".earth");
anim.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
  console.log('end !');
});
```

```css
.earth {
  position: relative;
  animation: move 10s linear;
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {
    left: 0%;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="earth"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried on the code, the alert at the end doesn't pop up @TemaniAfif

Comment: @Flicknk in my code i didn't use an alert, but a console.log ... did you change it with an alert ?

Comment: /////////Yes, I did

Comment: Yes, it's working I put it in the wrong part of the code, thank you!